# Why does IE complain about this js line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does IE complain about this javacript call?

```
$.get("profile_completeness.php?id=<?php echo($user_id); ?>", function(data) {
    var percentage = data.match(/id="percentage_complete" value="(\d+)"/)[1];
    alert(percentage);
})
```

This works fine in Chrome, and FF but IE throws an exception.

Here is the error I get:

```
Unable to get value of the property '1': object is null or undefined.
```

If I remove the var percentage line the error is gone.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the variable `data` doesn't contain what you think that it does.

This works just fine in IE:

```
var data = 'id="percentage_complete" value="42"';
var percentage = data.match(/id="percentage_complete" value="(\d+)"/)[1];
alert(percentage);
```

If you have created the string by using `innerHTML`, it will differ somehwat depending on the browser. You won't get the original HTML code that the elements were created from, instead the browser recreates HTML code from the DOM elements, and each browser have different ways of formatting the HTML code.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your answer.  The data returned from my php function is formatted differently between browsers?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Paul - What doesn't make sense is you not telling us what the exception was.

Comment: @Paul: That part of the answer doesn't apply to that part of your question, as you added that after I wrote the answer...

Comment: I think I found the issue...the value I'm looking for is part of a hidden input field.  Does IE have an issue with this?